# WP_List_Table Not showing any entries

Tags: php, wordpress, class, woocommerce

[Missing WP_List_Table Entries Screenshot Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYywC.png)

I'm trying to populate a list table in WordPress using WP_List_Table with country and state codes from WooCommerce, but it seems that either `:display()`, `:prepare-items()` or `:column_default` is failing me. Been staring myself blind for hours and I can't track down what's happening.

The class setup looks as follows:

```
<?php


if ( ! class_exists( 'WP_List_Table' ) ) {
    require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/screen.php';
    require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/class-wp-list-table.php';
}

class My_List_Table extends WP_List_Table {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct(
            array(
                'singular' => __( 'state', 'my-text-domain' ),
                'plural'   => __( 'states', 'my-text-domain' ),
                'ajax'     => false,
            )
        );
    }

    public function get_columns() {
        $columns = array(
            'cb'             => '<input type="checkbox" />',
            'col_state_name' => __( 'Region Name', 'my-text-domain' ),
            'col_state_id'   => __( 'Region Code', 'my-text-domain' ),
        );

        return $columns;
    }

    public function column_default( $item, $column_name ) {
        switch ( $column_name ) {
            case 'col_state_id':
            case 'col_state_name':
                return $item[ $column_name ];
            default:
                return $item;
        }
    }

    public function my_load_states() {
        if ( get_option( 'my_countries' ) && get_option( 'my_current_country' ) && get_option( 'my_states_' . get_option( 'my_current_country' ) ) ) {
            $states = get_option( 'my_states_' . get_option( 'my_current_country' ) );

            update_option( 'myplugin', true );
            return $states;

        } else {
            $states = WC()->countries->get_states( get_option( 'my_current_country' ) );
            if ( is_array( $states ) ) {

                return $states;
            } else {

                update_option( 'myplugin', true );
                return '';
            }
        }
    }

    public function get_states() {
        $data = array();
        if ( get_option( 'my_states_' . get_option( 'my_current_country' ) ) && ! empty( get_option( 'my_states_' . get_option( 'my_current_country' ) ) ) && get_option( 'my_country' ) && in_array( get_option( 'my_current_country' ), get_option( 'my_countries' ), true ) ) {
            $states = get_option( 'my_states_' . get_option( 'my_current_country' ) );
            update_option( 'myplugin', true );
        } else {
            $states = $this->my_load_states();
        }
        if ( ! empty( $states ) ) {
            foreach ( $states as $code => $name ) {
                $temp = array(
                    'col_state_name' => $name,
                    'col_state_id'   => $code,
                );
                array_push( $data, $temp );
            }

            return $data;
        } else {
            return '';
        }
    }

    public function prepare_items() {
        $this->_column_headers = $this->get_column_info();
        $this->process_bulk_action();
        $data = $this->get_states();
        if ( ! empty( $data ) && is_array( $data ) ) {
            usort( $data, array( &$this, 'usort_reorder' ) );
            $per_page    = count( $data );
            $total_items = count( $data );
        }
        $current_page = $this->get_pagenum();
        if ( is_array( $data ) && count( $data ) > 1 ) {
            $found_data = array_slice( $data, ( ( $current_page - 1 ) * $per_page ), $per_page );
        } else {
            $found_data  = $data;
            $total_items = 0;
        }
        $this->set_pagination_args(
            array(
                'total_items' => $total_items,
                'per_page'    => $per_page,
            )
        );
        $this->items = $found_data;
    }

    public function no_items() {
        esc_html_e( 'No states avaliable.', 'my-text-domain' );
    }

}
```

I'm initiating things through this:

```
<?php

class My_Admin {

    ...

    public function my_add_menu_item() {
        add_submenu_page(
            'woocommerce',
            'Locations',
            'Locations',
            'manage_options',
            'my_states',
            array( $this, 'my_settings_page' ),
        );
    }

    public function my_settings_page() {
        
        $slp_obj = new My_List_Table();
        $slp_obj->prepare_items();
        $slp_obj->display();
    }


}

?>
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging this, i.e., seeing step-by-step where the issue occurred?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is a late reply, but I have the same issue. What I did was initialize the table on-time, ref [here][1].

```
<?php

class My_Admin {
    private $slp_obj;
    ...

    public function my_add_menu_item() {
        $hook_name = add_submenu_page(
            'woocommerce',
            'Locations',
            'Locations',
            'manage_options',
            'my_states',
            array( $this, 'my_settings_page' ),
        );
        add_action( "load-$hook_name", array( &$this, 'init_table' ) );
    }

    public function init_table() {
        $this->slp_obj = new My_List_Table();
    }

    public function my_settings_page() {
        $this->slp_obj->prepare_items();
        $this->slp_obj->display();
    }


}

?>
```

[1]: [https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/360682/custom-wp-list-table-displays-blank-rows#:~:text=But%20try%20to%20always%20initialize%20it%20%22on%2Dtime%22.%20%3A](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/360682/custom-wp-list-table-displays-blank-rows#:%7E:text=But%20try%20to%20always%20initialize%20it%20%22on%2Dtime%22.%20%3A))

Comment: This is great - Thanks @WASD123; Just tested the code and that does the trick!